# Why am i not able to print escape sequence in editext in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, android-edittext

I am getting a response from an API using HTTP POST request which contains which contains some escape sequences such as \n, \t etc. When i try to display it in editText it is displayed as \n and \t but i expect a new line or horizontal tab. This is my code :

```
String out1 = sys.getString("stdout");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), out1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
String time1 = sys.getString("time");
if(compile.length()>0 && time1.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
    et.setText("Compilation error  "+"\n"+compile);
}
else if(compile.length()>0){
    et.setText("Runtime error  "+"\n"+compile);
}
else
    et.setText(message.substring(2,message.length()-2)+"  time: "+time1.substring(1,Math.min(time1.length(),4))+" memory: "+mem.substring(1,mem.length()-1)+"\n"+out1.substring(2,out1.length()-2));
//et.setText(result);
} catch(Exception e){ 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The JSON object stdout is something like "stdout":["5\n6"] and on printing it in editText it displays 5\n6 but i expect a new line. Is there any way to handle all escape sequences so as to properly display the result. I have been trying this for quite a while but cannot find a solution. Please guide me. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Try to send: `System.getProperty("line.separator");`.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working as expected. It is just adding a new line instead of handling escape sequences.

Comment: set multiline true to et...

Comment: @MSGadag That makes no difference :( Thanks anyways !!

Answer (score 1):

First, set your **editText** in  xml file like this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        .
        .
        .
        .
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
```

now put your text with new line character -

```
et.setText("Compilation error \n compile");
```

This works, enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `out1.substring(2,out1.length()-2)` with `out1`.