# How can I use "\n" differently inside a String[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have been looking thru some workarounds but nothing seems to work properly using API 15 of Android. I've tried:

- `System.getProperty("line.separator")`
- `"\r\n"`

Assuming that I will have a **huge** array of String (and I want to make it simple):

```
String[] values = new String[] { "This is a string \n array", 
"This is another \n string array"}; (...)
```

What's the best way to add a similar solution like

> \n

inside this array?

Comment: What's the result of the current operation?

Comment: What does "add a similar solution like" mean? And, what does this have to do with Android or Android Studio? This seems like a Java question.

Comment: The result is the same text without the "\n"

Comment: @CommonsWare I guess that he wants to preserve the new line created by the `\n` escape sequence

Comment: @CommonsWare the reason why I mentioned AS is because this implementation have always worked fine for me in Eclipse.

Comment: why you don't wanna use `\n`? It's the simplest thing to break a line

Comment: @Apurva I wish I could use but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with this `\n`
and in your xml file add this line to the `TextView`:
`android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

Comment: This call requires API 19, how can I use it on API 15? System.getProperty("line.separator") doesn't work

Comment: @Machado not sure but try `SuppressLint("New Api")` may it work

Comment: @Apurva while it may work on a 19+ device using this may cause erros on lower devices

Comment: @Machado see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635928/why-am-i-not-able-to-print-escape-sequence-in-editext-in-android/27646144#27646144) may be this will help you

Comment: TextView was missing `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` attribute on xml file. Thank you so much! Please edit your question so I can accept it.

Answer (score -2):

you need to escape the new line character in this way "This is another \\n string array"
\\   no \n

Comment: Yes, the web change the number of "\" I tried  to put 2 "\"

Comment: That doesn't work. Only makes the "\n" appears on the TextView.

Comment: If I understand your problem ... You want to show the strings in a TextView, but ... is set the TextView to use multi-line ??.

Even so, your method is pretty silly bad, there are better controls to display multiple texts than a TextView and there are better ways to have data in multiple dimensions